# Creating alias for bash exec command

Tags: bash, redirect, exec, alias, stderr

I want to redirect stderr of the exec command to `/dev/null`, like: `exec hostname 2> /dev/null`
for all the exec commands in my scripts.

As the very first solution I want to create an alias for that like this: `alias exec='function _myexec() { exec "$@" 2> /dev/null; unset -f _myexec; }; _myexec'`
but this and any other simple alias for exec just hanging.

I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: `exec(){ builtin exec "$@" 2>/dev/null; }`

Comment: @AliSalari : Also, what is the point in putting the function definition inside the alias? While this is not responsible for the effect you see, and not forbidden (you would simply replace the function definition by an identical one every time you invoke the alias), it is weird design and makes the code unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @user1934428: I'm actually not good in the bash. Thanks for your note. What I want to do is making a wrapper for exec to redirect stderr to a null. I still couldn't do that using the function with the same name. Could you please let me know what should I exactly do? Thanks.

Comment: Aliases don't work in scripts unless they are enabled with `shopt -s expand_aliases`.  An alias isn't a good way to do this anyway.
The function definition provided by @jhnc should work.  All of your scripts would need to execute the function definition before calling 'exec' though.  You could put the definition in all the scripts, or put it in a library that is sourced by all the scripts. If you can't get it to work, provide details of what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: @AliSalari : If you want to have an alias (which is not a good idea anyway), why do you want it to name it the same as a function? Just define a `with_a_very_long_and_descriptive_name` and then use your short, menmonic alias for calling it. But basically there are no cases where an alias is needed, and there are few cases where an alias has advantage over a function.